# how to provide encrypted image path

Tags: image

I got the below snippet from google. I am curious to understand and decode how image src path configured. Is the image name itself encrypted.

```
 <div><img class="imspo_tps__hs-img imspo_tps__hs-border" src="http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSIBJRTNFd7FodMrT8uvaTG9mZhP_ViztHyuSNvtkpEpg4_YIg7Kblkq2i-1l1HXgrfev0" style="width:42px;height:42px" alt=""></div>
```

Comment: Why not ask Google? First it is probably some binary represented as base-64 text. It can be everything you want like information about where it is stored, cache expiration time, the originator of the question, specifics for providing this image in particular region of the world, etc.

Answer (score 0):

What Google stores in their path ask Google.

To your question "how to provide encrypted image path": There can be many ways.

1. When you are creating deployment image, rename folders for instance with their hashes, rename the file nameswith their hashes. These changes should of course be done also in the application code (PHP, Java, etc. depending on what you use).
2. Implement hashing or other name replacing on a proxy level: encrypt/hash outgoing names and decrypt ingoing. Then your application code, folder names, file names remain unchanged.
3. If your users need to be authenticated, then you have some sort of session. May be it is a light weight session, but still you have at least unique user token. You can use that as an additional key to encrypt outgoing and decrypt ingoing URLs.